# Array<String> - get the character position of the word on the line number

Tags: java

I have an arrayList and it holds the contents of a file I read in. I just need help figuring out to get it to display the position of each word on that line for each line. (later I am to write a function that ignores the // and everything that follows that.

Desired output:
Line 1, Char/Position 1, Program
Line 1, Position 2 , Twenty:
Line 2, Position 3, int
and so on..

current out put reads:
Line Number: 0 line reads:  // This program should print the number 20.
Line Number: 1 line reads:  program Twenty:
Line Number: 2 line reads:    int a;
Line Number: 3 line reads:    int b;

Code:

```
public class Lex_functions {

    ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
    int lineNum = 0;
    int charNum = 0;
    int totalLines = 0;

    void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File("ab.txt");
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";
        boolean done = false;
        try {
            while (!done) {
                line = infile.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    list.add(line);
                }
            }
            infile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        for (String item: list) {
            //System.out.println(item);

            while (lineNum <= (list.size() - 1)) {

                System.out.println("Line Number: " + lineNum + " " + "line reads: " + " " + list.get(lineNum));
                //  System.out.println(list.size());
                lineNum++;
                charNum++;

                //System.out.println();

            }

            // System.out.println(list.indexOf(4));
            //System.out.println(list[0]);

            // System.out.println("Index of Program: "+list.get(2));
        } //end readfelil 
    }


}
```

Comment: Have a look at `BreakIterator`

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not exactly sure of what you want to do because the way you displayed the wanted output is not readable, and you did not give us the content of the file to display.
But if I understood well, if you have the following array :

{"Hello world"}, {"Have a good day"}

what you want to display should be :

- Word : Hello, Line number : 0, Word number 0
- Word : world,  Line number : 0, Word number 1
- Word : Have, Line number : 1, Word number 0
- Word : a, Line number : 1, Word number 1
- Word : good, Line number : 1, Word number 2
- Word : day, Line number : 1, Word number 3

So, to begin with there is an easy way to read all lines of a file into an Array List :

```
/**
     * Read a file and put all its content into a String List
     * @param fileName file path
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> readFileInList(String fileName){
        List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (ArrayList<String>) lines;
    }
```

Next is the way you do your loop...

```
for (String item: list) {
            //System.out.println(item);

            while (lineNum <= (list.size() - 1)) {

                System.out.println("Line Number: " + lineNum + " " + "line reads: " + " " + list.get(lineNum));
                //  System.out.println(list.size());
                lineNum++;
                charNum++;

            }

        }
```

What you do is essentially imbricating 2 loops that go through the same items. Facts are that a String is a list of char, so what you want to do is iterating through your String.
A String can also be divided into substrings with regex, creating a list of words :

```
/**
     * Parse the string (the line) into words. All spaces and dots are kept.
     * <br/> The following string
     * <ul>
     *     <li>"Hello, my name is Blanc! I'm a student. Can you help me? Thanks."</li>
     * </ul>
     *  will be parsed as :
     * <br/> "|Hello, |my |name |is |Blanc!| |I'm |a |student.| |Can |you |help |me?| |Thanks.|"
     * @param input the string to parse
     * @return the words of the input as an array
     * @see String#split(String)
     */
    public static String[] parseInputToWordsArray(String input) {
        return input.split("(?<= )|(?<=\\.)|(?<=\\?)|(?<=!)");
    }
```

Next you want to go through the lines of your array and their list of words to print the output (not tested but should work) :

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList();
        int lineNum;

        for (lineNum = 0; lineNum<list.size(); lineNum++) {
            int wordNum;
            String[] word = parseInputToWordsArray(list.get(lineNum));
            for(wordNum = 0; wordNum < word.length; wordNum++){
                System.out.println("Word : "+word[wordNum]+", Line Number : " + lineNum + ", Word Number: " + " " + wordNum);
            }

        }
```

Hope it could help